# Adaptative Pedal or crank for a handicap user

Tags: crankset, pedals, bike-fit, adaptive, adapter

I encountered a person with a disability in one leg. They are unable to control their ankle/heel movement. They are unable to maintain their foot parallel to the floor at the top of the pedal stroke (see picture). Their foot position means they are unable to get power to the crankset.

[image: issue and position due p. condition]

what type of solution can be the good one?
After searching in internet i've found some products but i have no clue about this matter.

- just a leg/ankle prosthesis inside the clip shoe?
- a Shortener on this side?
- a swing crank?
- a Pendulum crank?
- a Self Levelling Foot Sandal/pedal?
- other alternatives?

[image: pedal w calf fixation]
[image: pedal w calf fixation]
[image: weighted and ankle fixation]
[image: pendulum crank]

Comment: It would help to know whether 1. this applies to one leg or both and 2. whether a handcycle is a possible solution given their expense and recumbent nature.

Comment: it applies only to one leg (the right one on the picture). A hand cycle/trike  is not on the roadmap

Comment: If there is an adaptive cycling group near you, they are likely to be able to offer some help. E.g. Twin Cities Adaptive Cycling in Minneapolis, MN, US. The issue is that I don't believe they have a national organization with chapters in every state (e.g. National Alliance on Mental Illness in the US).

Comment: If possible, can you clarify what happens when the rider pedals? I think you're saying that they have to tilt their foot like shown in the pic. Are they unable to complete a revolution of the pedals?

Comment: Not sure what sort of pedal you've got there but without going to adaptive, would using standard clip in pedals be an option?

Comment: A quality MTB flat pedal might help if a clip is not suitable.

Comment: What exactly is the limitation? Would clip-in pedals help? Would significantly shorter crankarms help?

Comment: @Weiwen Ng the person is very limited about controlling the right leg, i.e the heel/foot tends to don't be horizontal with the floor (see picture) and this position not only doesn't help to spin the crankset but also can damage the foot/heel. A MTB clip pedal is being used to keep the foot t attached the pedal

Comment: Daniel, I tried to edit your comments into the main body. This may be clearer, but there's a chance that what I wrote differs from what you meant. Feel free to edit what I added or to undo the edit if you disagree. It may help if you can say if they have the range of motion to complete the pedal stroke; that means that their joints are able to move through the full range.

Comment: Is the rider able to wear a boot that goes up the ankle to restrain it in position?  Like a stiff jackboot or a small moonboot?

Comment: Yes, wear boot is possible but it would require to fix the boot to pedal. Whereas a ankle/middle leg prosthesis can be used with the MTB shoes and clip. It has to be tested.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick google image search for the terms "cycling leg prosthesis", And I see two main trends in the pictures: Some rides appear with prosthesis that have a foot, and seem to simply use a regular pedal.
Others appear to use a "footless" prosthesis that seem to clip directly to a normal pedal.

These two findings make me think that: 1) A helping support that would keep the ankle angle constant can be made strong enough to pedal, so the supports you added to the post are on the correct track. and 2) A person can pedal without a foot, by pressing the pedals directly bellow the ankle.

Maybe this 2nd point helps in this case, the reason being if you pedal with the heel, there is little torque trying to bend the ankle upward. This would also reduce the required "offset" in height between the two cranks.

I have seen people using different length cranks in the same bike, but never talked to them to learn more.

In my search, this video popped up and you may find it interesting. (not a product rec)